# What is the purpose of returning values in state changing functions?

Tags: solidity

I'm confused, as far as I know you can't get the returning value of state changing value funcions (unless the function is invoked from a smart contract), so what is the purpose of the return true in ERC20 approve function?

```
function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) 
{
    address owner = _msgSender();
    _approve(owner, spender, amount);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It is a way of communication between contracts.

Answer (score 0):

There are pros and cons to that.

Before going to them, if you are going to develop a erc20 token, you should follow the standard; otherwise, other contracts won't recognize your token as an erc20 token.

The explaination is long so I will share this [link](https://medium.com/coinmonks/missing-return-value-bug-at-least-130-tokens-affected-d67bf08521ca).

The above reason is enough to use return values in the erc20 tokens but if you ask what are the disadvantage is, it is gas costs. The function that returns something is costlier than something that doesn't.

One pro I can think of is that if you are writing a function that needs to require an approve, the return boolean can be useful there.

For example,

```
function foo(address spender, uint256 amount) public {
   require(approve(address spender, uint256 amount), "ERROR");
   ....
   ....
}
```

It is not just approve function. There are return values for transfer function too.

But in those situations, where you need to guard, it might be useful.

One more thing I can think of is when you are writing tests using web3.js or ether.js, return values can be useful to read the return values.

If you ask me, there is not meaningful explanation because when the approval fails, the transaction would revert to initial state. So I cannot wrap my head around it. But the standard and interface problem forced me to use the return values.

Once again, don't forget to add return values if you are creating an erc20 tokens. You can read the reasons above. It is a tad bit larger explanation but tell me if it helps!